# Unable to access the array i've created

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, constants

I'm a student, and I have to admit that I'm a little weak at my pointers, which is why I was given this exercise to practice. Currently my issue is that my program crashes in the markMines() function when it hits the printf. I believe its because it read a null. I've tried almost every way i could think of. I've checked where the issue starts from and its when I do *field = array; I've been at this for hours and I need a fresh pair of eyes to assist me. Also note that all the function parameters and main() are set and I cannot change them whatsoever. I've appended my code below.

```
int main(void)
{
    int **mine=0;
    int r,c;
    initField(&mine,&r,&c); 

    markMines(mine,r,c);    

    return 0;
}

void initField(int ***field, int *rows, int *cols)
{
    int r, c;
    int FieldInput = 0;
    int **array;

    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c );
    array = malloc((r)*sizeof(int));
    *rows = r;
    *cols = c;
    for(r = 0; r < *rows; r++)
    {
        array[r] = malloc((c)*sizeof(int));
    }
    field =&array;
    for(r = 0; r < *rows; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < *cols; c++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &FieldInput);
            array[r][c] = FieldInput;


        }
    printf("\n");
    }



  }

  void markMines(int *const*const field, int rows, int cols)
  { 
    int r = 0, c = 0;
    for(r = 0; r <rows ; r++)
    {  

        for(c = 0; c < cols ; c++)
        {
            printf("%d ", **field );
        }
    }
  }
```

I would appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions are entirely invalid.

The program can be defined the following way. Take into account that the functions should be declared before their usage in main.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void initField(int ***field, int *rows, int *cols);
void markMines( int *const*const field, int rows, int cols);

int main( void )
{
    int **mine = 0;
    int r, c;
    int i;

    initField(&mine,&r,&c); 

    markMines( mine, r, c );

    for ( i = 0; i < r; i++ ) free( mine[i] );
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    free( mine );
    //^^^^^^^^^^^                                   
}

void initField(int ***field, int *rows, int *cols)
{
    int r, c;
    int FieldInput = 0;
    int **array;

    scanf("%d %d", rows, cols );

    array = malloc( *rows * sizeof( int *) );
    //                             ^^^^^^
    for ( r = 0; r < *rows; r++)
    {
        array[r] = malloc( *cols *sizeof( int ) );
    }

    *field = array;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for ( r = 0; r < *rows; r++ )
    {
        for ( c = 0; c < *cols; c++ )
        {
            scanf("%d", &FieldInput);
            array[r][c] = FieldInput;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void markMines( int *const*const field, int rows, int cols)
{ 
    int r = 0, c = 0;

    for(r = 0; r <rows ; r++)
    {  
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; c++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", *( *( field + r ) + c ) );
            //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely marvelous! Thanks a bunch! Originally I didnt think much of it at first, but int * actually makes a huge difference. Also yea I prototyped the functions before the main, many of the questions in here feature code snippets, so I assumed that posting full source files would be redundant. Once again, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

- `array = malloc((r)*sizeof(int));` is wrong because the elements are `int*`, not `int`.
- `field =&array;` is wrong because it modifies the argument `field` instead of the variable `mine` in `main()`.
- `printf("%d ", **field );` might be wrong because it prints the same element for all iterations.
- You shouldn't call functions that are not declared before.
- You should free memory you allocated.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void initField(int ***field, int *rows, int *cols)
{
    int r, c;
    int FieldInput = 0;
    int **array;

    scanf("%d %d", &r, &c );
    array = malloc((r)*sizeof(int*));
    *rows = r;
    *cols = c;
    for(r = 0; r < *rows; r++)
    {
        array[r] = malloc((c)*sizeof(int));
    }
    *field = array;
    for(r = 0; r < *rows; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < *cols; c++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &FieldInput);
            array[r][c] = FieldInput;


        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void markMines(int *const*const field, int rows, int cols)
{
    int r = 0, c = 0;
    for(r = 0; r <rows ; r++)
    {

        for(c = 0; c < cols ; c++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(*(field + r) + c) );
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int **mine = 0;
    int r, c;
    initField(&mine, &r, &c); 

    markMines(mine, r, c);

    for(r--; r >= 0; r--)
    {
        free(mine[r]);
    }
    free(mine);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was very unsure about the array = malloc((r)*sizeof(int*)); at first. I assumed that it wouldn't make any difference if I used int instead of int*.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong size to `malloc` to allocate `array`. You need to allocate an array of pointers, not an array of `int`. Use:

```
array = malloc((r)*sizeof(int *));
```

or:

```
array = malloc((r)*sizeof(*array));
```

or:

```
array = calloc(r, sizeof(int *));
```

or:

```
array = calloc(r, sizeof(*array));
```

Comment: Thanks Ian for the input! I apologize if the question seems fairly newbie-ish, I just really suck at pointers. As the star count grows, so do the stars around my head.